# Host website on a different domain, but leave the mail

Tags: domain-name-system, email, website

I would like to host my website on a different server (Google Cloud), but leave the mail and DNS in my current server. See below my current Zone Editor. I think I should change the `indexambiental.com.br` destination to the new host IP and the type to A, and leave the `mail.indexambiental.com.br` the way it is, but I'm not sure. Can you help me please?

[image: Printscreen from the Zone Editor]

Answer (score 0):

Point the A record to your google cloud server and since you are using Google emails servers I think there is no need to change any thing with it.